# Python/Plotly: How to extract 'm' and 'b' from OLS line?

Tags: python, regex, string, plotly, text-extraction

I'm using **Plotly** lib to visualize my OLS Regression line and trying to extract '*m*' and '*b*' value from **y=mx+b** equation that shows up in the hover-template...

This is how it shows up in the hover-template when visualizing:

[image]

Using `ols_fcast_fig.data[1].hovertemplate` it prints out for me:

`'<b>OLS trendline</b><br>Observations = 0.000411 * Date + -603422.036990<br>R<sup>2</sup>=0.952751<br><br>Date=%{x}<br>Observations=%{y} <b>(trend)</b>'`

Now, I need to get *0.000411* and *-603422.036990* values. However, I need to get them in dynamic way as those values will be changing (so without using [#:#] index positions).
Please let me know how I can extract those in dynamic way, **such that first value is after '= ' and before ' *' and second value is after '+ ' and before '<*br*>'.** Thus, is it possible to do within Plotly functions or without using regex?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: I have tried using _.split(<br>)_ - It got me as far as having `'Observations = 0.000411 * Date + -603422.036990'` extracted, however not exactly what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access these numbers directly, **you don't need to parse any strings**!

Plotly Express stores the results of the `statsmodels` fit. Check out https://plot.ly/python/linear-fits/#fitting-multiple-lines-and-retrieving-the-model-parameters

For a simple case where you have only one facet, this will print the two parameters:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", trendline="ols")    
fit_results = px.get_trendline_results(fig).px_fit_results.iloc[0]
print(fit_results.params)
```

Comment: Thanks, using `fit_results.params[0]` and `fit_results.params[1]` is exactly what I was  looking for!

Comment: That's what we built it for! Sorry it wasn't clear enough in the docs :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with OLS and Plotly, and I think it's likely that there's an easier way to access those value, but just to extract them from the text you can use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) like this one:

```py
import re
text = '<b>OLS trendline</b><br>Observations = 0.000411 * Date + -603422.036990<br>R<sup>2</sup>=0.952751<br><br>Date=%{x}<br>Observations=%{y} <b>(trend)</b>'

numbers = re.findall("(-?\d[\d.]+)", text)
first_value = numbers[0] # 0.000411
second_value = numbers[1] # -603422.036990
```

Note that this will not work with numbers in scientific notation or if there are other numbers before the ones you want to extract in the text (both issues can be solved if needed by making the pattern more complex)

Without using a regex you can do something like

```py
first_value = text.split('Observations = ', 1)[1].split(' ')[0]
second_value = text.split('Date + ', 1)[1].split("<br")[0]
```

But I would advise against this approach, as it quickly becomes messy and brittle

Another alternative would be using the [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) library

```py
n1, n2 = parse.search("<br>Observations = {} * Date + {}<br>", text)
```

Comment: Yes, I hope there is an easier way without using regex as I am not familiar with it; however, your solution would work for this case as I will not have numbers in scientific notation or anything else unexpected before... thanks!

Comment: Regex tend to be very useful, while intimidating at first. I've edited the answer with alternatives